# Buffer tool not working in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer

[enter link description here](https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:d2ded7ea-76f2-3fcb-b28d-56957c036cd4)> [Blockquote](https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:8dc9dbb9-6e25-3895-8181-3fdbc5fee650)

- The two hyperlinks above are the explanations of the assignments 1 and 2 from a GIS course provided by Coursera which I am currently taking.

See the page 29 of the second file ('Blockquote': IntroductionToArcMap_part2.pdf) for the buffer problem which I am trying to tackle. I wanted to upload the files as well, but it seems that I cannot upload any files in the post.

I am a beginner using ArcMap 10.8.2. (ArcGIS Desktop) and I am trying to apply a 100m buffer tool, but nothing has changed. No layer has been created and nothing happens. I have no idea how to make the buffer tool work.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

after applying the buffer tool:
[image]

And when I try to close the programme, a warning message pops up. It says that:

> the map document has executing and/or pending geoprocessing
> operations. All operations will be stopped and you can view them
> within the map document Results later. Are you sure you want to
> continue?

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What does "nothing changed" mean? What are the units of your map canvas?  What are the units of the buffered feature class? How many features are present in the layer?  How many features are *selected* in the layer? What does your instructor say you should try?

Comment: Two things: 1 - The units in your map are DD...that may be an issue...2) which I think may be more valid...whats up with your output path? Try changing it to something else...I do not recognise the symbols used...try C:\temp\buffer.shp as a first try.

Comment: What's the output of the tool?  What messages does it log?

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to my question. I am a native Korean speaker, so my English is not very good. Sorry for that! And please kindly understand that I might not understand exactly what the units or features are in the ArcGIS, as I began learning ArcGIS three weeks ago. This is part of the assignments for Fundamentals of GIS course provided by Coursera. I'll attach the relevant documents and files in this post. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate that.

Comment: I added two hyperlinks of the assignments 1 and 2 at the upper part of the post. You can see the buffer problem at the page 29 of the second PDF (Blockquote : IntroductionToArcMap_part2.pdf). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you please verify that your map's coordinate system is set as explained on the page 6 of the part2 of your course material?

Comment: Yes, I did set my map's coordinate system as explained on the page 6.

Comment: I agree with Allan regarding the output path. Have you tried using `\` as separator?

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 1):

At [Error: Cannot start editing while there are pending background processes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/cannot-start-editing-while-there-are-pending-background-processes.htm#:%7E:text=There%20are%20pending%20geoprocessing%20operations,before%20beginning%20an%20edit%20session.) there seems to be the same symptom that you are seeing even though the trigger for it may be closing an edit session rather than closing ArcMap.

In any event, I think you should either pay more attention to background geoprocessing or simply turn it off and run geoprocessing in the foreground (which I prefer) by going to your Geoprocessing Options - see [Foreground and background processing](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/foreground-and-background-processing.htm#:%7E:text=You%20can%20control%20whether%20tools,in%20foreground%20or%20background%20mode.).